# Cycling through two lists for all pairwise combinations

Tags: r, loops, lapply

There are two lists including many matrices:

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(100,sample(0:100,100,rep=TRUE)))
l.i <- vector("list")
l.j <- vector("list")

for (var in names(df[1:50])) {
   l.i[[var]] <- as.matrix(dist(df[var], "euclidean"))
}

for (var in names(df[51:100])) {
  l.j[[var]] <- as.matrix(dist(df[var], "euclidean"))
}
```

I want to compute Mantel tests between all pairwise elements in `l.i` and `l.j` (but not within them). I can do e.g.:

```
library(vegan)
all.i.vs.j1 <- lapply(l.i, function(x) mantel(x, l.j$X51))
all.i.vs.j2 <- lapply(l.i, function(x) mantel(x, l.j$X52))
```

and this would be indeed my desired output environment, but i would like to wrap this into a for loop or lapply.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Map` to apply the function `mantel` on corresponding elements of 'l.i' and 'l.j'

```
library(vegan)
out <- Map(mantel, l.i, l.j)
length(out)
#[1] 50
```

---

If we need pairwise, then use `outer`

```
f1 <- function(x, y) list(mantel(x, y))
out1 <- outer(l.i, l.j, FUN = Vectorize(f1))
```

Comment: Nice. Can it be adjusted to give the pairwise combinations of all elements in both lists? It was mentioned in the title, but not explicitly in the text.

Comment: @nouse. You can use `outer`

Comment: @nouse updated the post.  Please check if that helps

Comment: great use of `Vecotirze`!

Comment: yes, works like a charm. The nice thing is the output of 'out1', which is a pairwise matrix of all elements. What is the best strategy to write the output if i am mainly after out1[[x]][3] and out1[[x]][4]?

Comment: @nouse `out1` is a matrix of `list`.  so you can extract the elements with row.column index i.e. `out1[3, 3]` gets the 3rd row, 3rd column element.  Similarly `out1[3, 3:4]` gives the 3rd and 4th column elements from the 3rd row

Comment: @akrun is there a way to name the objects inside the matrix according to their row and colnames?